# How to get StartOfDay and EndOfDay, in UTC

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I have a NestJS application where I need to work with dates. Everything works perfectly when I run the app locally, but things get messy when I move the code to my server, which is in the UTC timezone.

For example, here's a code snippet I'm using:

```js
async onModuleInit() {
    const date = new Date();
    const startDate = startOfDay(date);
    const endDate = endOfDay(date);

    console.log(date);
    console.log(startDate);
    console.log(endDate);
    console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone);
}
```

When I run this code on my local machine, I get the following output:

```
2023-10-12T19:45:19.289Z
2023-10-12T18:30:00.000Z
2023-10-13T18:29:59.999Z
Asia/Calcutta
```

However, when I run it on my server, I get a different result:

```
2023-10-12T19:51:06.553Z
2023-10-12T00:00:00.000Z
2023-10-12T23:59:59.999Z
UTC
```

here is an example on how i use it in a query

```js
.leftJoin( "shift.attendances", "attendance", "attendance.createdAt BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate", { startDate, endDate }.
```

is this correct ? does `TypeOrm` or `Node` manage this difference correctly? if i run it from my local or the server would the data i get from the query be the same? based on the time?

can someone help me understand how these conversions work properly?

Comment: Seems normal? If you want the same dates between your server and your clients, always use UTC dates with explicit UTC timezone, and only convert it to a local time when you need to render it as "just a string" (e.g. on a webpage).